# Gradually bring git repo to synch with upstream

Tags: git, github

I'm taking over the code-base of an application that was pulled from a project hosted in github.
Currently it's lagging behind one year of commits and I intend to gradually include the changes from the original github repository.

The plan is to fork the original repository in github, have code point to the new repository, commit the changes that were made since the code was pulled from github and then start merging the commits from upstream slowly (one by one).

My question is how do I go about doing this procedure?

1. Fork repository in github (No problem here)
2. Make the code point to a specific branch/commit of the new repository (currently it's in status: HEAD detached at xyz123)
3. Commit the changes that were made after the initial pull
4. Merging the changes from upstream one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed as if the upstream development were happening at the pace you want to integrate it.  Refnames are completely repo-local, smoosh them around to whatever point in history you want to pretend is current at the moment, integrate, repeat.  What refnames you alter on push is also completely arbitary.